# Vim - copy to system clipboard on Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: ubuntu, vim, digital-ocean

I am ssh-ing into Digital Ocean Droplet — from an iPad Pro through Termius should it matter..

Droplet is Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64

Vim 8.0 — with +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard

I have set `clipboard=unnamed` In my .vimrc, though have tried variations of clipboard+ and unnamedplus.

I am able to copy in a single terminal (tmux window) but I am not able to copy between terminal instances. I believe this might have something to do with the system Display env var, but not sure. Also from reading around seems like folks get touchy about modifying Display as it (maybe) can be no-bueno. Currently echo $DISPLAY returns nothing for me. I believe I should be getting back :0.0 as documented by Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch about `$DISPLAY` is correct, Vim's clipboard support wants to talk to an X11 server and `$DISPLAY` is how it can find one.

But just setting `$DISPLAY` to something isn't likely to fix this, since you don't seem to have any X11 server running anywhere.

If you wanted to share the clipboard with your iPad, then you'd need an X11 server running on the iPad. (Does such thing even exist? There's an X11 server for MacOS X but I don't think there's one for the iPad.)

Furthermore, you'd need to use "X11 forwarding" in your SSH application and it doesn't look like Termius supports that at all...

So I guess getting `"+` or `"*` to work in this setup will be fairly hard to do and possibly quite limited... You may want to stick to the normal terminal selection and copy & paste, assuming your terminal client even has enough support for that.